# Django 1.9 Cannot resolve keyword 'models' into field. Choices are: comm, id1, id2, id2_id

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.9

Having these two models:

```
class Models(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    genes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'models'

class ModelInteractions(models.Model):
    id1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.ForeignKey('Models')
    comm = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('id1', 'id2'),)
```

I'm trying to select `comm` (from `ModelInteractions`) but also with `name` (from `Models`), for specific `request_id` (ID received with the request).

I'm using:

```
# request_genes example = "ab-2;cra-19"
genes = request_genes.split(';')
condition = Q(id2=request_id)
for field in genes:
    condition &= Q(models__genes__icontains=field)
models = ModelInteractions.objects.filter(condition)
```

This returns:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'models' into field. Choices are: comm, id1, id2, id2_id.
```

Without for loop everything works fine, but I don't have `Models` data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
for field in genes:
    condition &= Q(id2__genes__icontains=field)
models = ModelInteractions.objects.filter(condition)
```

`Models` is the name of the table. When performing queries, use field_names as keyword arguments for the manager method `filter`.

Comment: Yes, this worked. One more question: how can I show `name` (from `Models`) in template? `{{ model.name }}` after loop doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would you do me favour and tag my answer as selected, then?

Comment: Welcome... Appreciate the support buddy!!